# Elapsed time using System.nanoTime() around several method calls delivers a lower value than the sum of of the elapsed times in each method?

Tags: java

I'm using System.nanoTime() to measure the time it takes to call several methods.
In each of those methods I do the same to measure how long each method takes.
In the end the sum of the elapsed times should be smaller than the total elapsed time, or so I thought. However, it isn't.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  long startTime = System.nanoTime();
  method1();
  method2();
  method3();
  System.out.println( "Total Time: " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000);
}
private void method1(){
  long startTime = System.nanoTime();
  //Stuff
  System.out.println( "Method 1: " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000);
}
// same for all other methods
```

In my case I get something around 950ms for the total time, but the sum of each elapsed time is 1300ms+. Why is this?

EDIT:

Okay, to be a bit clearer, I am *not* getting this behaviour when writing to arrays many times (which I just did as a test). When I do this, I get pretty much exact results (+-1ms).

What I am actually doing is this:

I read two pretty huge text files into String arrays (1000 * ~2000 characters in first file, 200 * ~100 characters in the second).

I then do a whole lot of comparisons on the String array I got from reading the first file and use the results to calculate some probabilities.

EDIT2: Error on my part, I was calling methods within methods and summed up those times as well, which were already included. Without these double-times it all adds up. Thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: Are they all in the same thread?

Comment: all in the same thread, yes.


Tried without dividing,
Sum = 1 280 182 306
Total = 953 483 065,
so no, it's not rounding errors.

Comment: To get better answers, you should try to create a minimal example that reproduces the behaviour. That will help people better assess what the problem can be.

Comment: How much can the JVM reorder code involving System.nanoTime? The symptom could be explained by executing two of the nanoTime calls in reversed order, so that a small slice of time is counted twice.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I don't think it is even allowed in a single threaded environment because of the sequential consistency requirement.

Comment: Well, when I run something really simple like writing to arrays many times then the sum of elapsed times and total time is off by 1ms, which is fine to me.
In my actual project I'm not doing anything too fancy either, I read Strings from two files and then work on those Strings a lot and do some calculations.

Comment: Do you literally have three method calls that you sum, or many? Because summing many small numbers can accumulate a lot of error.

Comment: Which OS are u running? I'm asking, because I remember that System.nanoTime() uses OS-specific calls and there were some strange behaviours on Windows with missing C:\boot.ini flags on multicores.

Comment: @Marko No, 5. I am not really summing these up, though, I am just printing them to see how long each takes and at first glance I can see they sum up to more than the total time (and actually summing them up revealed a difference of some 400ms every time).

Win7 64bit Professional, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To further investigate this thing, maybe you can print out the start and end time of each method and of the global process. Here you are just printing the time taken by each one and the total time, but you can output something like this:

```
Global start   : (result of System.nanoTime() here)
Method 1 Start : ...
Method 1 End   : ....
Method 2 Start : ....
Method 2 End   : ....
Method 3 Start : ....
Method 3 End   : ....
Global end     : ....
```

Why I suggest you to do this is the following: you expected `GlobalEnd - GlobalStart` to be greater than or equal to `(End1-Start1) + (End2-Start2) + (End3-Start3)`. But this relation actually derives from the fact that if everything is sequential the following holds true:

```
GlobalStart <= Start1 <= End1 <= Start2 <= End2 <= Start3 <= End3 <= GlobalEnd
```

Isn't it?

Then what would be interesting for you is to know what is not true in this list of inequations. This could possibly give you some insight.

Comment: run:
    Main Method Start: 30495884497522
    Method 1 Start: 30495885305501
    Method 1 End: 30496199920982
    Method 1 Start: 30496199980102
    Method 1 End: 30496200498200
    Method 3 Start: 30496201642783
    Method 2 Start: 30496201691097
    Method 2 End: 30496264901276
    Method 3 End: 30496637264023
    Method 5 Start: 30496637324414
    Method 4 Start: 30496637348253
    Method 4 End: 30497332544531
    Method 5 End: 30497364712059
    Main Method End: 30497376773253
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
Jesus, can you really not format these comments?

Comment: Thank you for giving your results. Apparently Method 2 and 3 are running concurrently (that is, one starts when the previous one has not finished), and methods 4 and 5 too. What is each of these methods doing?

Comment: BTW, tell me, you are not calling method 2 from method 3, and method 4 from method 5, aren't you ?

Comment: I am, actually. Method 3 calls 2, 5 calls 4. Which is why start and end times fit(?)

Comment: And you sum the elapsed time in 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 ?? When you call 2 from 3, the elapsed time in 2 is INCLUDED in the elapsed time of the method 3. So they can not be summed. You can just sum times in 1, 3 and 5 if you want meaningful results.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with your code. In my testing I got the correct elapsed time from your code.

Here is my output:

Method 1: 600
Method 2: 500
Method 3: 10
Total Time: 1110
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: I get exact results (off by 1ms) when only writing to arrays a lot.
In my actual project I'm reading two files into Strings, do a whole lot of comparisons on those Strings and calculate some stuff.
My best guess right now is that since I'm running it on a multicore CPU that's what's messing up the time (read somewhere that nanoTime() can be faulty on multicores).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your doe to something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    long elaspeTime = 0;
    elaspeTime += method1();
    elaspeTime += method2();
    elaspeTime += method3();
    System.out.println("Total Time: " + elaspeTime / 1000000);
}

private static long method1()
{
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    //Do some work here...
    System.out.println("Method 1: " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000);
    return System.nanoTime() - startTime;

}
```